# Registering repository using generics with multiple types <T, T> c# dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm creating a generic repository as follows:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
  {
    Task<T> GetById(int id);
    Task Add(T entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    Task<int> Save();
    Task Delete(int id);
    void Delete(T entity);
    T Update(T entity);

  }

  public abstract class Repository<T, TContext> : IRepository<T> where T :
  class where TContext : DbContext
  {
    protected readonly TContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _table;
    protected Repository(TContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
      _table = _context.Set<T>();
    }
    // implementation
   }
```

I'd like to pass any DBcontext to my implementation, a concrete implementation shoulb be something like this:

```
public interface ICouponRepository : IRepository<Coupon>
  {
    Task RedeemCoupon(int id, Guid userId);
  }

  public class CouponRepository : Repository<Coupon, CouponApiDBContext>, ICouponRepository
  {
    private readonly CouponApiDBContext _couponApiDBContext;

    protected CouponRepository(CouponApiDBContext couponApiDBContext) : base(couponApiDBContext)
    {
      _couponApiDBContext = couponApiDBContext;
    }

    public Task RedeemCoupon(int id, Guid userId)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

then I'm registering both services as follows:

```
 services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<,>))
              .AddTransient<ICouponRepository, CouponRepository>()
```

but I can get to instantiate the generic repository, I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
> xxx.dll: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type
> 'xxx.Repositories.Repository`2[T,TContext]' for service type 'xxx.Repositories.IRepository`1[T]'.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things come immediate to mind.

The first is nothing to do with your question but `CouponRepository` should not have its own member for `_couponApiDBContext` it has access to the base class `TContext` - that's the whole point of having it generic in the first place.

The second is that you are specializing `IRepository<Coupon>` with `RedeemCoupon` method in `ICouponRepository` - so you have zero chance of registering an open generic type and just expecting DI to know what actual interface you're after.

You're left with removing this `AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<,>))` - it's pointless as DI cannot instantiate an abstract class anyway, and that is the root cause of your error message and you should register  `AddTransient<ICouponRepository, CouponRepository>()` and request `ICouponRepository` where you need it - you cant ask for `IRepository<Coupon>` as that will not have your `RedeemCoupon` method which I assume you need.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, changed the approach made it to work